# Calling Function From Controller In JS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

As in my code below, i am trying to run the function `pay()` after the script is run. I inserted an ajax request in the script to handle the `pay()` but after the function getPaidSetup is successful, the `pay()` is not run.

Am i doing it the right way please? Any help is appreciated.

```
 <script>
         document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {

        getpaidSetup({
          PBFPubKey: PBFKey,
          customer_email: "eg.com",
          customer_firstname: "Temi",
          customer_lastname: "Adelewa",
          custom_description: "Pay Internet",
          amount: 2000,
          customer_phone: "2342423423",
          currency: "USD",
          country: "US",
          "txref": "MG-" + Date.now(),
          onclose: function() {},
          callback: function(response) {
            var flw_ref = response.tx.flwRef; // collect flwRef returned and pass to a                  server page to complete status check.
            console.log("This is the response returned after a charge", response);
            if (
              response.tx.chargeResponseCode == "00" ||
              response.tx.chargeResponseCode == "0"
            ) 
            {
              // redirect to a success page

            } 
            else 
            {
              // redirect to a failure page.
            }
          }
        });

     $.ajax({
        url: "/monthly_plan/basic",
        type: "post",
        data: {field_name :'data'}
     });

      });


    });



    </script>
```

**Controller**

```
 public function pay(Request $request)
    {
        $starter = new Payment(array(
            'plan_id' => 1,

        ));

        $starter->save();
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/monthly_plan/basic',['uses'=>'Controller@pay']);
```

Comment: you need to put ajax call in the callback function

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara how is that? I am new to this

Comment: just put your ajax code blow the `// redirect to a success page`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Database table `payments` is still empty

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Yeah 500 error pointing to my URL(route)

Comment: you can't just give the route like  this `/monthly_plan/basic` it should be `http://localhost:8000/monthly_plan/basic` you need to give the full path in you ajax `url`

Comment: Okay. All i had to do was to change the action from `post` to `get` and it works now.